# How should I pass my prop to get a valid Array[Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use [react-json-table](https://github.com/arqex/react-json-table) to build a simple data table in a react/redux project. When I'm passing the data directly inside my component, everything is working fine. However when I'm using `props` the table doesn't show up.

So here is my code when I'm hard coding the data :

```
var data = [{'alpha': 82, 'bravo': 20, 'charlie': 68}];
<JsonTable rows={ data } />
```

It's working fine.

But when I'm passing the exact same data through my prop directly like this `<JsonTable rows={ props } />` it doesn't work. I've check my props with a `console.log({props})`, it's working fine.

any idea ? Do I need to format my prop in a specific way before using it ?

thanks.

Comment: is your props an object or array. ? what is you output when you do `console.log(typeof props)` and `console.log(props)` Please make sure there is no curly brackets surrounding your props in the console statement.

Comment: so the typeof is Object. and when doing `console.log(props)` I've got this `Object {alpha: 82, bravo: 20, charlie: 68}`... so I guess it's an object, and I guess I need a array. Is this my problem ?

Comment: Yes. Be sure that you are passing the data as an array to this component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you are passing the data as an array in the props to this component:

```
<JsonTable rows={[props]}/>
```

Comment: Ok that was easy! Sorry I could have found this myself. so the differences between an array and an object is just about [..] or {...} ?

Comment: In Javascript an array is declared with square brackets `[]` and a literal object with curly braces `{}`. The keys in an array are its indexes (0,1,2,etc.) and in an object the keys can be strings ({'myKey': 'myValue'}) or also integers. In your case `JsonTable` expected an array of objects to represent each row and you provided an object, which broke the component.